# Using Blend InvokeCommandAction on button in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, behavior, blend

I am learning WPF using the MVVM pattern. I am trying to use the InvokeCommandAction behavior on a button. In Blend, I placed a button on my view. I then dragged the InvokeCommandAction onto the button.

Blend displays the Properties tab. The trigger is set to "Click". I set Command to CloseCommand : (IComamnd) in my view using the "Create Data Binding" dialog.

This generates the following XAML

```
<Button x:Name="CloseApp" Content="Close" >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

CloseCommand is a RelayCommand : ICommand from MSDN. The project compiles, but when I click on the button, the command does not execute. Any ideas, or sample code to point me to.

Comment: Could you please post the implementation of the `ViewModel`?

Comment: We figured out the problem was the DataContext of the button was not set properly.  Dragging the InvokeCommandAction onto the button was not setting the DataContext correctly.